# Device driver engineer looking for more lower layer opportunity

Tags: developer

Hi I am a graduate in IT and I was currently working for a company which maintains a user mode driver codebase.

First days I came here , it was well challenging and I felt everyday that I was learning something new. I was playing the music with everyday is a new day and everyday is a new competition. Those are golden days of my life even I was treated as an probation dude.

Now things are changed,The driver is getting matured and feels like there's no new challenge on it, please don't took me as an attraction seeker, because this is how I felt when I lose my life music. So I was up to find some better opportunity in the same company, a driver engineer opportunity which is in kernel level. Since nobody read the linux kernel completely everyday would be a new day and I don't run out of such work challenge.

I am an opposite guy from one who asked this question.
[Driver software engineer interested in transition to Web/App development](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27829/driver-software-engineer-interested-in-transition-to-web-app-development)

And the guys who came here with me are also associates and they were top from all the universities all around the country. However some are stable and still have work challenge with their job, however what I know is nobody is working in the kernel level in my teams. Anyway I don't know how they feel, but pretty sure they will started to feel boring very very soon.

I don't have a master degree in computer science in my hand and only have 8 months of experience since this is my first job. My question how could I explain them that my desires and potential with less experience and qualifications but that I really up to such kernel level driver job?

Answer (score 4):

8 months into your first job and you;re getting a bit bored. Well done, most entry level jobs are boring well before 8 months. Unfortunately for someone so junior it is unlikely that your bosses will allow you to pick your own work, or make up your own job. The realities of the workforce is that it is often boring. The better you get the more mundane the jobs seem.

I think you should get at least a year under your belt before you start pushing hard for different work and responsibilities. With just 8 months no one will take you all that seriously, and your colleagues may think you're getting a swelled head and be a bit offended which could affect their attitudes towards you.

Comment: so you are saying that there is no option. And at least I have to wait another 4 months ? I'll be honest , actually they didn't push me that hard in first 6 months but I did myself due to my interest and self satisfy. However now things are different. May be  I didn't get what industry need,very slow but matured solution. 
Actually there were things to learn in that 6 months even it's a user mode driver base.

Comment: there is always options, you can basically ask for anything you want. But expect people's perception of you to change if you do so. At this early stage in your career, what other people think can have a huge impact on your career.

Comment: There was opportunity for a kernel mode driver developer, but that hiring manager asks around 5+ years experience in the job advertisement. My current manager and current leads are completely on my side and they are willing to recommend me even. So anyway I'm going to apply and see what happen right. Will it get bad impression on me if I apply and failed that ? So I have to deal with that risk and that was what I'm asking.

Comment: I would think it's ok, nothing wrong with applying for any position you think you can fill. It's up to the employer to give it to you or not. Failing to get a position you apply for is not a disgrace. I think most people have failed an interview. I have failed several :)

Comment: @sandundhammika, you can apply for the position, but if they are asking for 5 years experience, your competition will likely be far more skilled than you are.  In many organizations it is likely they would never even see your resume as HR would screen it out.

Comment: @HLGEM that would definitely be the norm, for an internal position and with managerial backing the OP might have a chance, a slim one. No real harm in trying anyway in terms of creating a bad impression.

Answer (score 2):

> Since nobody read the linux kernel completely everyday would be a new day and I don't run out of such work challenge.

Since this is your first job you may not know it yet, but you can (and will) run out of enthusiasm at any job. No job can be 100% stimulating for years and years, there will be highs and lows. Experience will help you overcome the lows with discipline.

My attitude to deal with boring stretches at work is to imagine it as a recharge period, because being too intense all the time will lead to burnout.